# How to make a SpringWeb jar listen to IPv4 on a Linux server

Tags: java, linux, ipv6, ipv4

I uploaded a SpringWeb application (with embedded Tomcat) executable JAR file(wrapped by maven) to a Linux server. When I run this JAR file on my local (Windows) system, it can listen to both IPv4 and IPv6. However, when I run it on a Linux server in the cloud, it can only listen to IPv6. I don't know how to make it listen to IPv4. This is the Controller, and it's all what I intend to do and there is nothing else special in the properties or config file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3BUt.png),this is what it listens to on Windows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE7JU.png)and this is all the listenings on Linux, the one listen on :::8080 is the executable jar, I have no idea why it's only on IPv6 and not IPv4

I hope someone can tell me why there is a difference on the listening address, I have open the 8080 port and shutdown the firewall, I want to know is somewhere on the Linux that controls the avaliable listening address ? Here are the starting logs on console(first is in IDEA,second is on the command line on Linux) nothing essential difference:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2llb.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFvst.png)Both of them run without any exception or error.

Comment: Did you try `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`? Lots of moving parts here: it's not just Java, Linux, but also factors such has how the network is configured for a given host, over which your app has no control

Comment: Please share errors and codes in plain text format